# How can I connect two different database(mongo and postgres) in springboot with JPA?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm making mongo to postgres migraiton tool with springboot. But when I try to connect with mongo and postgres base on [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources) documents, spring just raise `dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.` error.

this is my application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    legacy:
      url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
      username: "root"
      password: "root"

    migration:
      url: "jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017"
      username: "root"
      password: "root"
      database: "fromdb"
```

and to use two different types of DBMS, I config my configurations. (**If it doesn't required, please let me know better way**) and because of hibernate.dialect doesn't support MongoDBDialect, it also raise `Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set` error.

this is my legacy db configuration code

```
import part

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "migrationEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "migrationTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.dbmigrater.DBMigrater.repository.migration"
)
public class MigrationDBConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari.bootdb1")
    public DataSource migrationDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager migrationTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(migrationEntityManager().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean migrationEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(migrationDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.dbmigrater.model.migration");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        //=================This part is setting dialect, and error=====================//
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", org.hibernate.dialect.MongoDBDialect);
        //=============================================================================//
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }
}
```

Because mentioned error, I should set dedicated part in my upper code. but it also causes error`properties.put("hibernate.dialect", org.hibernate.dialect.MongoDBDialect);` because hibernate.dialect does not support MongoDBDialect!!

How can I connect these two databases(mongo, postgres)??

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. configuration code should be modified like below:

```
package com.dbmigrater.DBMigrater.config;

import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "migrationEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "migrationTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "com.dbmigrater.DBMigrater.repository.migration"
)
public class MigrationDBConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.migration")
    public DataSource migrationDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager migrationTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(migrationEntityManager().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean migrationEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(migrationDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.dbmigrater.DBMigrater.entity.migration");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", PostgreSQL82Dialect.class.getName());

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }
}
```

point is inner parameter of @CongifurationProperties() should be matched with application.yml. In this case, I change my parameter by `spring.datasource.migraiton`.

and because of I face the next error for mongo driver, I change my application.yml like below

```
spring:
  datasource:
    legacy:
      driver-class-name: "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
      jdbcUrl: "jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017"
      username: "root"
      password: "root"
      database: "fromdb"
    migration:
      jdbcUrl: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
      username: "root"
      password: "root"
```

Also, mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver is not a exist class, I face another error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader`

If I solve this secondary problem, I will leave the solutions